# I read a book some years ago about dragons and a glass paperweight

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I read a book some years ago about another world with dragons. The protagonist was a female who could travel to this otherworld through a glass paperweight (snowglobe?). She was a history graduate or something like that? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you remember approximately when you read it? What the cover looked like? Paperback or hardback?

Answer (score 6):

This is actually a sequence of three books, ***Dragonsword*** (1989), ***Duel of Dragons*** (1991), and ***Dragon Death***, all by Gael Baudino.

[image]

The main character is Susan Helling, a graduate student and teaching assistant in history at UCLA.  In the first novel, she is transported to the dragon realm of Gryylth, a world created by her comatose PhD supervisor's subconscious.

The glass paperweight you mention plays an important role in the second novel.  (The dragon Silbakor, the main dragon of the first novel, uses the glass paperweight to stow himself away to the real world.)

From the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel_of_Dragons) of *Duel of Dragons*:

> The story picks up a few weeks after Suzanne has returned to Los Angeles from Gryylth. Silbakor has returned with her and poses as statuette in a **glass paperweight**. Though she carries Silbakor around with her and can return to Gryylth at will, she finds she cannot bring herself to do it.